# Can ChromeCast receiver POST messages to a service?

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

## Context

There are several sender apps that will use the same receiver, there is the need to generate/output some use stats and error reporting.

## Question

Can we implement an ajax POST/PUT in the receiver? This would be preferable as it centralizes all the logic in one end, avoiding duplication of code. Plus it's the receiver state that need to be sent to the service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Receiver is just an HTML5 app (HTML / Javascript / CSS).  You can generally do whatever you like. Everyone's life is better if your custom receiver includes our recommended include, `//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/receiver/2.0.0/cast_receiver.js` and follows basic protocol.  Once thats done, you can do what ever you want.

We anticipated that many developers will want to start activities using their sender, but get the next actions from a server.  Server Queue's, and other uses are clearly desirable.

So, to answer your question, YES, you can implement POST / PUT in the receiver.  You should be able to include any standard analytics, or logging systems you wish.

Comment: Thank you @les-vogel-google-devrel. That makes sense. One thing I don't fully understand is what do you mean with *"Server Queue's, and other uses are clearly desirable"*...

Comment: You can implement a play list or Queue on the server.  For example, you can queue various YouTube videos to a watch queue, once you begin playing that queue with your sender, it will take the next video from the queue by contacting the server.

Comment: Another use would be an app for displaying useful business data on your TV.  You would start Chromecast using a Sender, and then the Chromecast would go out to the cloud to get the data.  This could include from various sources -- I expect to see lots of interesting applications for this including Sales trackers, in/out boards, etc.

Comment: Great! Thank for the heads up! For a moment I was thinking in queue for threads/processes, the ones that are not visible to the client ;)

Comment: Is there any way to implement google-anyalytics and capture the user's events like which video are playing, duration etc.